# Password check program

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm busting my head on this for quite a while. This password checker program ensures that the given password includes:

- Both upper and lower case letters
- At least 10 digits
- At least one number

The code works almost fine, with the exception of capital letters. When a single capital is inserted as the password, the program changes the value of flagncap, while it shouldn't. Can anyone help?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter password: "
read user_passwd
flaglng=0
flagcap=0
flagncap=0
flagnum=0
if [[ ${#user_passwd} -ge 10 ]]; then
    flaglng=1
fi

if [[ "$user_passwd" = *[A-Z]* ]]; then
    flagcap=1
fi

if [[ "$user_passwd" = *[a-z]* ]]; then
    flagncap=1
fi

if [[ "$user_passwd" = *[0-9]* ]]; then
    flagnum=1
fi

if [[ "$flaglng" == 1 && "$flagcap" == 1 && "$flagncap" == 1 && "$flagnum" == 1 ]]; then
     echo "Password Strong!"
fi

if [[ "$flaglng" = 0 ]]; then
   echo "Weak Password! It should include at least 10 characters."
fi

if [[ "$flagcap" = 0 ]]; then
    echo "Weak Password! It should include at least 1 upper case letter."
fi

if [[ "$flagncap" = 0 ]]; then
    echo "Weak Password! It should include at least 1 lower case letter."
fi

if [[ "$flagnum" = 0 ]]; then
    echo "Weak Password! It should include at least 1 number."
fi
```

Comment: `export LC_ALL=C`

Comment: What @AlexP said. What is the output of `echo LC_ALL` or just `locale`? Also, what letters are you using? Based on your name, you might not be using a latin script. Don't expect this to work if your password is `κάτιΤέτιοΞέρωΓω`.

Comment: Related: https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: @dobey please don't vote to close this sort of question. They are completely on topic here and always have been.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but have you considered *perhaps* using a separate thing like a Python script (which assumes a basic "C" locale unless you specify otherwise) for this instead of a Bash script which is going to be heavily-based on locale?

Comment: @terdon It's a general programming question, though. So why is _this_ one any more on topic than all the others that are not? Because it's a bash script instead of C/C++/Python/Javascript/COBOL? This sort of question is far better answered on StackOverflow than on here.

Comment: @dobey yes, precisely because it is a bash script instead of C/C++/Python/Javascript/COBOL. Also note that questions about programming in those languages would also be on topic as long as the question is about communicating with the Linux API or other Linux and/or Ubuntu-specific stuff. Please see the [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) page in the help center ("Development on Ubuntu") and [this meta discussion](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13807/85695).

Comment: I'm not going to put this as an answer, as this is almost certainly a homework question, but if anyone else cares, this same Bash program was replicated with a bit less conditional complexity (and a lot more loops heh) in Python, and as Python defaults to the "C" locale and *not* whatever locale is set on your shell for its execution environment, it works and does everything the Bash version did.  [The code for it is Python3, and is up on this Gist](https://gist.github.com/teward/9a5d541376ca30372ec1f0ae225df58d) if you're interested.

Comment: @terdon Well that's self-contradictory.  And there are multiple ways to answer this, with varying personal preferences. But whatever.

Comment: For example, I would state that this script would give one a false sense of password strength, even having had it return "Good password!" to the user.  The script suggests that "Ab00000000" is a strong password, when it very clearly is not, and would be cracked by a brute force hashing tool very quickly. One should thoroughly read and understand the current NIST password strength recommendations, as well as understand additional threats against password attacks, before endeavoring to create such a tool.

Comment: Why is this on Ask Ubuntu rather than a programming related SE site?

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev please see above. Because the shell is an integral part of any Linux system and shell questions have always been on topic here. We have several *thousand* of them! And because, furthermore, developing on Ubuntu has also always been on topic.

Comment: @dobey not self contradictory. General programming questions are on topic here, as stated in the help center, as long as they are about developing *on Ubuntu*.  So as long as the question relates to interacting with the Ubuntu system. Shell scripting questions are even more on topic because shell scripts are the basic tool used to administer a Linux system. As for your answer, that sounds great! Why don't you post a better script and add that as a discussion? Note that this is almost certainly a homework assignment designed to test shell knowledge though, not security.

Comment: It is self contradictory because "Hello world" programs are off topic, even if one is developing it _on Ubuntu_. You also claim this is _almost certainly a homework assignment_, which is also off topic, falls into the "hello world" category, and is certainly not something used to _administer a Linux system_. I use Python/Perl far more in administration of Linux systems, than shell scripts, but this same question in that context, would be off topic, and redirected to StackOverflow.

Comment: @terdon So if I post a C++ question that uses the Linux system calls and is developed on Ubuntu, would I not get redirected to a different SE site?

Comment: @dobey I'm afraid you don't know the scope of this site very well. None of the examples you cite are inherently off topic. We have loads of questions about Perl or python scripts for sysadmin tasks. I've never understood why people think they are off topic. Granted, the line can indeed get blurry, but this one isn't near the line at all. But please take this to meta or ping me or another mod in chat. Let's not do this in the comments.

Comment: @dmitry if the question is about the Linux API then it would be on topic here. Whether this is the best site for it is debatable, but yes it is within the site's scope. We also try to help developers writing programs for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

First, you do *not* need that many branching `if`s. Like, at all. Instead, do something like this:

```
goodpassword=1

...

if [[ "$user_passwd" = *[A-Z]* ]]; then 
    echo "Weak Password! It should include at least 1 upper case letter."
    goodpassword=0
fi

...

if [[ "$goodpassword" = 1 ]]; then
    echo "Good password!"
fi
```

To fix your issue with the globs, use regular expressions instead. Drop the `*` and use `~`.

```
if [[ "$user_passwd" =~ [A-Z] ]]; then 
    flagcap=1
fi
```

Regexes in general give you way more control and capability with matching and verification. You can, in fact, condense this entire script down into a single regular expression if you wanted (though you will lose verbosity).

Sample:

```
$ ./pwcheck.sh 
Please enter password : 
a
Weak Password! It should include at least 10 characters.
Weak Password! It should include at least 1 upper case letter.
Weak Password! It should include at least 1 number.

$ ./pwcheck.sh 
Please enter password : 
A
Weak Password! It should include at least 10 characters.
Weak Password! It should include at least 1 lower case letter.
Weak Password! It should include at least 1 number.
```

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you work with character ranges it's a very good idea to insert `export LC_ALL=C` (or `C.UTF-8` if you need support for characters outside the ASCII range) at the beginning of the script, otherwise you may be surprised by what `A-Z` and `a-z` mean...

For example:

```
$ unset LC_ALL
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ [[ 'abc' = *[A-Z]* ]] && echo Match || echo No match
Match
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ [[ 'abc' = *[A-Z]* ]] && echo Match || echo No match
No match
```

The shell takes the range `[A-Z]` to mean all characters which sort between `A` and `Z` in the current locale. In the `en_US` locale `b` sorts between `A` and `Z`; hence `abc` matches `*[A-Z]*`. On the other hand, in the `C` locale `b` does not sort between `A` and `Z`, because in the `C` locale characters sort strictly in accordance with their code point.